# How to generate data for a particular column from mysql + php

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with columns:

ULB Gender MaritialStatus Category

possible values for gender (M, F)  for maritial status (Married, Unmarried, Widow, Divorcee)  for category (General, Reserved) and ulb is a list of 200 places

Now I want to write queries to generate a report in a format which is given in the below image.

[image]

where F_M => Female Married, F_D => Female Divorced, F_UM => Female Unmarried, F_W => Female Widow etc

I know how to run single queries to data one by one but is there any way to generate this report in a more compact and query saving way.

Comment: Use subqueries for each condition ,show what you tried

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple queries within one, these can give you an idea:

```
select t1.c, t2.c, t3.c
from
  (select count(*) as c from new_table where date11="08/01/2015") as t1,
  (select count(VchType) as c from new_table where date11="08/01/2015") as t2,
  (select sum(Debit) as c from new_table where VchType="CASH SALES GODOWN") as t3;
```

Or:

```
SELECT 1 AS Deptnumber, Dept FROM tbl_students WHERE Dept IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
UNION
SELECT 2 AS DeptNumber, Dept FROM tbl_students WHERE Dept IN ('D', 'E')
UNION
SELECT 3 AS Deptnumber, Dept FROM tbl_students WHERE Dept IN ('F')
```